# Java applet redraw refresh

Tags: java, applet

My project is trying to implement java processing.core.Papplet to display a graphics with different color( Random color changing by times). It is so weird that I can only use:

```
  applet.mousePressed();
```

to refresh my applet.
And I also tried:

```
        applet.redraw();
        applet.updatePixels();
        applet.loop();
        applet.redraw();
        applet.noLoop();
        applet.redraw();
        applet.draw();
```

But neither of them works in my project. This means I can refresh my Papplet by either Robot mouse click or mouse click to make my applet refresh.
Does anybody know what's going on?
Appreciate for your great help.

BTW, I have tried the invoke method:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                target.refresh();
                previewController.render(target);
                applet.redraw();    
            }

        });
```

It can force flash the applet, but with some error image. I don't know what's going on with Papplet mousePressed.

Comment: FYI: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: Actually I try source code of Papplet at https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fprocessing%2Fcore%2FPApplet.java#L107. But I don't find any ideas,